# ChartJS ReactJS Object of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have an object like this:

```
data = {
  "day1": {
    "found": 0,
    "lost": 3
  },
  "day2": {
    "found": 1,
    "lost": 2
  },
  "day3": {
    "found": 0,
    "lost": 3
  }
}
```

I would like to use ChartJS to display this on a line graph, with day1,day2,day3 being the label and found/lost to be the 2 different lines. I have tried using something like this, but I was hoping there was some more dynamic way in case a 3rd key would be added into the inner object than pushing it all into an array. Or maybe a way of doing it without having to first store all the values in an array first.

```
var found = [];
var lost = [];
Object.entries(data).map(([key]) => {
     [rates[key]].map(row => {
         found.push(row.found);
         lost.push(row.lost);
      })
    });


<Line
    data={{
      labels: Object.keys(data),
      datasets: [
        {
          data: found
          label: "found"
          borderColor: "blue",
          fill: true,
        },
        {
          data: lost
          label: "lost"
          borderColor: "red",
          fill: true,
        }
      ],
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract the labels:

```
const labels = Object.keys(data);
```

Then the values:

```
const found = labels.map(label => data[label].found);
const lost= labels.map(label => data[label].lost);
```